# Creating an image of a triangle centered at the centroid

Tags: python, geometry, turtle-graphics, centroid

Excuse me as I am a little new to programming. Basically, I am assigned to "analyze" and produce an image of a triangle where the user specifies the lengths of two sides and the size of the angle between them, the program runs and finds the length of the third side as well as the two other angles (using Law of Cosines). Then I must have text outputs for all sides lengths, all angle measures (optional), and also print the area in the form of my turtle printing out "Here is your triangle \n It has an area of x square pixels" in the image as well.
Also, the triangle must have its centroid at (0,0). This is what I have so far:

```
import math
from turtle import*



print("This program will draw a custom triangle.")
firstside=float(input("Enter length of first side (between 10 and 400 pixels): "))
secondside=float(input("Enter length of second side (between 10 and 400 pixels): "))
includedangle=float(input("Enter the measure of the included angle in degrees (between 1 and 179): "))

print("Side lengths and angle measures:\n")





solvedthirdside=float(math.sqrt(firstside**2+secondside**2-(2*firstside*secondside*math.cos(includedangle))))

cage=Screen(); #Create screen object named cage
cage.setup(500,500) #set screen size to 500x500 pixels
```

Also, I am using the turtle graphics for this too.

I am really struggling with this. Some help would be greatly appreciated!
Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Python statements _do not_ end in semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

This is not finished, but should be a lot easier to work on now.

I have thoroughly factored it into functions and commented heavily; it should be pretty easy to understand. Hope that helps!

```
import math
import turtle

def get_float(prompt):
    """
    Prompt for input and return it as a floating-point number
    """
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def third_side(a, b, C):
    """
    Given a triangle defined by two sides and
    the angle between them (in degrees),
    return the length of the third side
    """
    return math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2 - 2. * a * b * math.cos(math.radians(C)))

def get_sides():
    """
    Prompt for a triangle as two sides and an angle,
    calculate the length of the third side,
    and return the three side lengths
    """
    side1 = get_float("Length of first side  (pixels, in 10..400)? ")
    side2 = get_float("Length of second side (pixels, in 10..400)? ")
    angle = get_float("Included angle (degrees, in 1..179)? ")
    return side1, side2, third_side(side1, side2, angle)

def get_angle(opp, left, right):
    """
    Given three sides of a triangle,
    return the angle opposite the first side (in degrees)
    """
    cos_opp = (left**2 + right**2 - opp**2) / (2. * left * right)
    return math.degrees(math.acos(cos_opp))

def get_angles(a, b, c):
    """
    Given three sides of a triangle,
    return the three angles (in degrees)
    """
    return get_angle(a, b, c), get_angle(b, c, a), get_angle(c, a, b)

def main():
    print("This program will draw a custom triangle.\n")
    side1, side2, side3    = get_sides()
    angle1, angle2, angle3 = get_angles(side1, side2, side3)

    print(
        "\n"
        "Sides and angles:\n"
        "a = {side1:>5.1f}    A = {angle1:>5.1f}\n"
        "b = {side2:>5.1f}    B = {angle2:>5.1f}\n"
        "c = {side3:>5.1f}    C = {angle3:>5.1f}\n"
        .format(
            side1=side1,   side2=side2,   side3=side3,
            angle1=angle1, angle2=angle2, angle3=angle3
        )
    )

    # Your code continues here!

if __name__=="__main_":
    main()
```

Comment: I really want to say thank you man for taking the time to do this! This is greatly appreciated and really helps!